# Install AWS Toolking For Visual Studio 2017 for MAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, toolkit, visual-studio-mac

Is there a way I can install `AWS Toolkit` For `Visual Studio 17` on `MAC`?

I downloaded the toolkit from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017. If I open it with Visual Studio, it opens the file as a text editor.

I downloaded Visual Studio Community Edition from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: Visual Studio Extensions (`vsix`) currently only work in Visual Studio for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio does not support Visual Studio for Mac. See below:

https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/

It still does not on 21/03/2021.

Answer (score -2):

Open your VS Code and go to "Extensions" on the left hand side and click on it. Search for AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code. Once you find it, it's a fairly straightforward process to install it!

Comment: Not true. It's not available there as of now as Visual Studio for Mac isn't supported as of now.

Comment: visual studio and vs code are different things